# file not found eclipse issue

Tags: java, eclipse

When I parse a file saved in my `C:\` drive my application runs. When i save the file in my `eclipse folder` and modify my code  I get a "`file not found error`".

***Any suggestions ?***

I have tried modifying  "`String ebookName = "SomeBook.txt`";"

```
if (selected.equals("1"))
{
    ParseQuery pq = new ParseQuery();
    String ebookName = "C:\\\\Assignments\\\\Java\\\\text-files\\\\SomeBook.txt";
    try
    {
        pq.parse(ebookName);
        System.out.println("parsed Ebook");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception found while reading the E-book: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

the file saved in eclipse folder should be parsed.

Comment: Looks like the file does not exist, double check the location of ebookName and make sure it exists

Comment: `new java.io.File("SomeBook.txt").getAbsolutePath()` - does that return what you expect it to?

Comment: joe. where would i use your code ?